# If multiprocessing is doing X processes, there is a way to make another multiprocessing use total cpu process minus X?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Specifications regarding the *CPU* of my computer that uses *Windows 11* (values retrieved while a 4-task multiprocessing was running):

```python
import psutil
import multiprocessing

print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
# 12
print(psutil.cpu_count())
# 12
print(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
# 6
print(len(psutil.Process().cpu_affinity()))
# 12
```

I have two different projects that run on my computer at the same time throughout the day, both of which sometimes need to use *multiprocessing*.

Currently, as the maximum number of rows in *dataframe* of each project is `4`, so the total maximum they can reach if activated together will be `8` *process*.

So I can keep it like this:

```python
def stackoverflow(stack):
    df = create_dataframe(stack)
    if len(df) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
            list_pool = pool.map(data_event, zip(repeat(stack), df.iterrows()))
        finally:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

But, let's say that now I want to leave the *dataframe* unlimited, being able to have `1` row up to, for example, `1000` rows, whatever...

I could put `5` as the limit value for each *Pool*, but when one of them happens to have only `2` rows and the other `8` rows, the one with `8` rows would be harmed because it could be using more cpu.

The example below is just to visually demonstrate what I want to do, it is totally unfeasible for multiple factors.

In a bizarre and erroneous way, I could try saving the value that will be used in a *CSV* file, then the other one before starting the *multiprocessing* would take that value and at the end of the *multiprocessing* it would save it as `0`:

```python
def stackoverflow(stack):
    df = create_dataframe(stack)
    if len(df) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        another_mp = int(list(csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\multiprocessing_B.csv')))[0][0])

        free_to_use = 10-another_mp

        with open(r'C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\multiprocessing_A.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            f.write(free_to_use)

        try:
            max_process = free_to_use
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
            list_pool = pool.map(data_event, zip(repeat(stack), df.iterrows()))
        finally:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            with open(r'C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\multiprocessing_A.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                f.write(0)
```

And I would do it in the other one too, just inverting the substring `A` and `B` in the name of the files that are opened.

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: There's nothing inherently bad about starting or keeping more processes than you have cpu cores. If a process is idle, it won't do anything but take a little ram. Python sometimes has issues with long running processes accumulating ram and not releasing it, so it is sometimes good to re-start long running processes. on the other hand, creating and destroying the `pool` all the time is very inefficient cpu-wise.

Comment: if you have more active processes than cores (not idle), the OS will schedule them all to run periodically, and modern OS schedulers are very good at balancing speed (less frequent swapping between processes) and fairness (no one process gets totally starved for execution time).

Comment: "Is there a correct way to do this?" yes: don't. Create all the processes you need, and let the OS handle scheduling. Also, make sure your processes don't [busy-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) when they're idle..